# How does Spark deal with JDBC data in relation to time?

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to sync my Spark database on S3 with an older Oracle database via daily ETL Spark job. I am trying to understand just what Spark does when it connects to a RDS like Oracle to fetch data.

Does it only grab the data that at the time of Spark's request to the DB (i.e. if it fetches data from an Oracle DB at 2/2 17:00:00, it will only grab data UP to that point in time)? Essentially saying that any new data or updates at 2/2 17:00:01 will not be obtained from the data fetch?

Comment: can you explain the question with code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it depends. In general you have to assume that this behavior is non-deterministic, unless explicitly ensured by your application and database design.

By default Spark will fetch data every time you execute an action on the corresponding Spark dataset. It means that every execution might see different state of your database.

This behavior can be affected by multiple factors:

- Explicit caching and possible cache evictions.
- Implicit caching with shuffle files.
- Exacted set of parameters you use with JDBC data source.

In the first two cases Spark can reuse already fetched data without going back to the original data source. The third one is much more interesting. By default Spark fetches data using a single transaction but there methods which enable parallel reads based on column ranges or predicates. If one of these is used Spark will fetch data using multiple transactions, and each one can observe different state of your database.

If consistent point-in-time semantics is required you have basically two options:

- Use immutable, append-only and timestamped records in your database and issue timestamp dependent queries from Spark.
- Perform consistent database dumps and use these as a direct input to your Spark jobs.

While the first approach is much more powerful it is much harder to implement if you're working with per-existing  architecture.